# Многопоточное программирование, сокеты.

Tags: c++, сокет, многопоточность

Пишу приложение. В определенный момент, я создаю несколько потоков с помощью _beginthread. Совместно используемые объекты я синхронизирую с помощью критических секций. Но программы вываливается с ошибкой в дебагере.
Вот изображение:
[image]

Для сокетов использую обвертку собственного производства.

Comment: Как раз изображение, которое Вы привели, наименьшее что могло бы вызвать интерес. Покажите код, который падает. Если это строка с iResult = getaddrinfo(...)
то проверьте корректность передаваемых входных параметров. Чему, в частности, равен addrresult.

Comment: В однопоточном режиме все хорошо. И этот код прекрасно работает.
Вот заголовочный файл:
http://pastebin.com/UuxfzPZP
Вот cpp:
http://pastebin.com/xM8mP0Zq

Comment: А метод c_str() точно реентерабельный ? Вообще, видимо, где-то лишний free() затаился.

Comment: WSACleanup завершает операции с сокетами для всех потоков сразу, а у Вас её вызов как-то неаккуратно распространён по коду

Comment: Ага, походу точно библиотека. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виной оказалась не правильная инициализация WSA библиотеки. Для правильной работы, ее необходимо инициализировать, а после чего использовать сокеты. Когда все потоки, работающие с сокетами остановятся, библиотеку следует деинициализировать.

Comment: Т.о. если WSACleanup() не вызывать, то ошибки бы не было ?

Comment: Угу.